# How to maintain circle velocity after colliding with a square?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, collision-detection, game-physics

I'm developing a game where the player is a circle and tiles are squares. The user moves the avatar (circle) with the keyboard, and should not be able to collide with tiles (squares).

Also, I would like the circle to slide along the square if they hit the corner, such that if the player keeps pressing the key to move in the same direction, they will slide along the square instead of getting stuck on it.

I've developed a full reproduction of the problem I'm facing here:

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

class Vec2 {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
  }

  distance(v) {
    let x = v.x - this.x;
    let y = v.y - this.y;

    return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
  }

  magnitude() { 
    return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
  }

  dot(v) { 
    return this.x * v.x + this.y * v.y;
  }

  normalize() {
    let magnitude = this.magnitude();
    
    return new Vec2(this.x / magnitude, this.y / magnitude);
  }
  
  multiply(val) {
    return typeof val === "number" ? new Vec2(this.x * val, this.y * val) : new Vec2(this.x * val.x, this.y * val.y);
  }

  subtract(val) {
    return typeof val === "number" ? new Vec2(this.x - val, this.y - val) : new Vec2(this.x - val.x, this.y - val.y);
  }

  add(val) {
    return typeof val === "number" ? new Vec2(this.x + val, this.y + val) : new Vec2(this.x + val.x, this.y + val.y);
  }
}

function clamp(value, min, max) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max);
}

function drawCircle(xCenter, yCenter, radius) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(xCenter, yCenter, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawSquare(x, y, w, h) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function circleRectangleCollision(cX, cY, cR, rX, rY, rW, rH) {
  let x = clamp(cX, rX, rX + rW);
  let y = clamp(cY, rY, rY + rH);

  let cPos = new Vec2(cX, cY);

  return cPos.distance(new Vec2(x, y)) < cR;
}

function getCircleRectangleDisplacement(rX, rY, rW, rH, cX, cY, cR, cVel) {
  let circle = new Vec2(cX, cY);

  let nearestX = Math.max(rX, Math.min(cX, rX + rW));
  let nearestY = Math.max(rY, Math.min(cY, rY + rH));    
  let dist = new Vec2(cX - nearestX, cY - nearestY);

  let tangentVel = dist.normalize().dot(cVel);

  // The original answer had `cVel.subtract(tangentVel * 2);` here
  // but that was giving me issues as well
  return cVel.add(tangentVel);
}

let circlePos = new Vec2(150, 80);
let squarePos = new Vec2(240, 110);

let circleR = 50;

let squareW = 100;
let squareH = 100;

let circleVel = new Vec2(5, 0);

draw = () => {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#b2c7ef";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 800); 

  ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";

  drawCircle(circlePos.x, circlePos.y, circleR);
  drawSquare(squarePos.x, squarePos.y, squareW, squareH);
}

update = () => {
  draw();

  if (circleRectangleCollision(circlePos.x, circlePos.y, circleR, squarePos.x, squarePos.y, squareW, squareH)) {
    circleVel = getCircleRectangleDisplacement(squarePos.x, squarePos.y, squareW, squareH, circlePos.x, circlePos.y, circleR, circleVel);
  }

  circlePos = circlePos.add(circleVel);
}

setInterval(update, 30);
```

```css
canvas { display: flex; margin: 0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas width="800" height="800"></canvas>
```

If you run the snippet you'll see that the circle correctly moves around the square, but afterwards it moves down and to the right. I'm not sure why this is happening. It should just keep moving completely straight and to the right afterwards.

Unfortunately I'm not very good at math, so I'm having trouble figuring out why this is happening. I learned of the main algorithm [through this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45373126/962155), but also used the following answers as a reference:
[One](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7305/top-down-rpg-movement-w-correction)
[Two](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4059/how-to-make-the-player-slide-smoothly-against-terrain)
[Three](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49956/collision-detection-smooth-wall-sliding-no-bounce-effect)

Another issue I noticed is that if you change the y position of `circlePos` from `80` to `240`, then it still slides along the top of the square, instead of taking the more natural path of sliding along the bottom of the square. I'd like to fix this as well if possible.

In addition, ideally there shouldn't really be any sliding at all if the circle hits the tile straight on, if that makes sense. It should get stuck against the square in that case.

Comment: As to your last paragraph: the demo has the circle hitting "straight on" (I understand this to mean: perpendicular to the square's side), so why should it slide? Or is the condition for sliding that the circle hits the square on a corner? What if it hits the side? What if it hits the side, but not in a perpendicular way?

Comment: @trincot Sorry I don't think I explained that properly. I'm not sure of the proper way to explain it, but basically, if the circle comes straight at the square but only barely clips the edge of it, it should slide around it. Similar to what happens in this GIF: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/joa8cdeddygje5f/round.gif But if the circle approaches the square such that the majority of the circle is clipping into the square, then it should just get stuck next to it. It only slides around the square if it is barely colliding with it, if that makes sense.

Comment: Is the initial movement of the circle always pure horizontal, or pure vertical? What if the circle fully hits the square in a diagonal path... should it also stick?

Comment: No the initial movement of the circle can certainly be diagonal, as the player (circle) can move in any of 8 directions using WASD. To be honest I'm having difficulty understanding _exactly_ when it should stick, and I'm not sure if there is even an objective answer for that. Basically, I just want to improve upon the current situation where the player always gets stuck on the edges of collidable square tiles when walking around, as it's very frustrating to play with. I would like to favor sliding in as many situations as makes sense. Sorry that my answer isn't very technical.

Comment: I see, so movement is actually never like 15° inclined, but only 8 directions, multiples of 45°

Comment: Hey, I just woke up, so sorry for the late reply. I'm looking at your answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest these changes:

Define two more methods in your class:

```
  crossProductZ(v) {
    return this.x * v.y - v.x * this.y;
  }
  
  perpendicular() {
    return new Vec2(this.y, -this.x);
  }
```

In `getCircleRectangleDisplacement` replace the `return` statement with:

```
return dist.perpendicular().normalize()
           .multiply(cVel.magnitude() * Math.sign(cVel.crossProductZ(dist)));
```

The idea is that the circle should move perpendicular to the line through the center of the circle and the hit point (which is `dist`). There are of course two directions on the perpendicular line: it should be the one that is at the same side of `dist` as is the current velocity vector. That way the circle will choose the right side of the square.

The magnitude of that move should be equal to the magnitude of the current velocity (so that there is no change in speed, just in direction).

Finally, also make this change to the `update` function:

```
  let nextCirclePos = circlePos.add(circleVel);
  if (circleRectangleCollision(nextCirclePos.x, nextCirclePos.y, circleR, squarePos.x, squarePos.y, squareW, squareH)) {
    let currentVel = getCircleRectangleDisplacement(squarePos.x, squarePos.y, squareW, squareH, circlePos.x, circlePos.y, circleR, circleVel);
    nextCirclePos = circlePos.add(currentVel);
  }
  circlePos = nextCirclePos;
```

The idea here is that we first do the move as usual (`circleVel`) and see if that would mean a collission. In that case we *don't make that move*. Instead we get the displacement *from the current position*.

And, we never update `currentVel`. That will guarantee that the movement will continue as before once the obstacle is out of the way.

In the snippet below these changes are made. In addition I added a second square in the path of the circle, and once the circle is out of view, I added a second run where the circle takes a different path:

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

class Vec2 {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
  }

  distance(v) {
    let x = v.x - this.x;
    let y = v.y - this.y;

    return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
  }

  magnitude() { 
    return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
  }

  dot(v) { 
    return this.x * v.x + this.y * v.y;
  }

  normalize() {
    let magnitude = this.magnitude();
    
    return new Vec2(this.x / magnitude, this.y / magnitude);
  }
  
  multiply(val) {
    return typeof val === "number" ? new Vec2(this.x * val, this.y * val) : new Vec2(this.x * val.x, this.y * val.y);
  }

  subtract(val) {
    return typeof val === "number" ? new Vec2(this.x - val, this.y - val) : new Vec2(this.x - val.x, this.y - val.y);
  }

  add(val) {
    return typeof val === "number" ? new Vec2(this.x + val, this.y + val) : new Vec2(this.x + val.x, this.y + val.y);
  }
  
  crossProductZ(v) {
    return this.x * v.y - v.x * this.y;
  }
  
  perpendicular() {
    return new Vec2(this.y, -this.x);
  }
}

function clamp(value, min, max) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max);
}

function drawCircle(xCenter, yCenter, radius) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(xCenter, yCenter, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawSquare(x, y, w, h) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function circleRectangleCollision(cX, cY, cR, rX, rY, rW, rH) {
  let x = clamp(cX, rX, rX + rW);
  let y = clamp(cY, rY, rY + rH);

  let cPos = new Vec2(cX, cY);

  return cPos.distance(new Vec2(x, y)) < cR;
}

function getCircleRectangleDisplacement(rX, rY, rW, rH, cX, cY, cR, cVel) {
  let circle = new Vec2(cX, cY);

  let nearestX = clamp(cX, rX, rX + rW);
  let nearestY = clamp(cY, rY, rY + rH);
  let dist = new Vec2(cX - nearestX, cY - nearestY);

  return dist.perpendicular().normalize().multiply(cVel.magnitude() * Math.sign(cVel.crossProductZ(dist)));
}

let circlePos = new Vec2(100, 80);
let squarePosList = [new Vec2(240, 110), new Vec2(480, -50)];

let circleR = 50;

let squareW = 100;
let squareH = 100;

let circleVel = new Vec2(5, 0);

draw = () => {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#b2c7ef";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 800); 

  ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";

  drawCircle(circlePos.x, circlePos.y, circleR);
  for (let squarePos of squarePosList) {
    drawSquare(squarePos.x, squarePos.y, squareW, squareH);
  }
}

update = () => {
  draw();

  let nextCirclePos = circlePos.add(circleVel);
  for (let squarePos of squarePosList) {
    if (circleRectangleCollision(nextCirclePos.x, nextCirclePos.y, circleR, squarePos.x, squarePos.y, squareW, squareH)) {
      let currentVel = getCircleRectangleDisplacement(squarePos.x, squarePos.y, squareW, squareH, circlePos.x, circlePos.y, circleR, circleVel);
      nextCirclePos = circlePos.add(currentVel);
      break; // we only deal with one collision (otherwise it becomes more complex)
    }
  }
  circlePos = nextCirclePos;
  if (circlePos.x > 800 + circleR) { // Out of view: Repeat the animation but with a diagonal direction
       circlePos = new Vec2(100, 400);
       circleVel = new Vec2(3.6, -3.6);
  }
}

let interval = setInterval(update, 30);
```

```css
canvas { display: flex; margin: 0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas width="800" height="800"></canvas>
```

NB: You have some code repetition in the collision and displacement functions. They both calculate almost the same thing. This could be optimised.

Comment: Thank you for such an amazing answer! I'm trying to implement it into my game now though, and I'm having a bit of trouble. It seems like the player sometimes gets stuck inside of the squares. I've noticed this happens in the code you provided a bit as well. For example, if you set `circleVel` to `(3, 3)`, `circlePos` to `(35, 80)` and `squarePosList` to `[new Vec2(140, 180), new Vec2(140, 280), new Vec2(140, 380)];`, the circle not only sometimes glitches inside, but also sometimes gets stuck, as seen in these screenshots: https://i.imgur.com/J1f2q0l.png and https://i.imgur.com/6uxbhpj.png

Comment: This problem is resolved by removing the `break` in my solution, but I am aware that things can get tricky if you have complex arrangements of squares that can be hit simultaneously. This goes a bit beyond the original question. Ideally you should merge adjacent squares to one rectangle, and adapt the code to work with rectangles.

Comment: Hmm, I can't really do that (turn groups of squares into rectangles) in my game because the player moves on a grid of tiles. Like imagine 2d top-down legend of zelda game, where solid walls and collidable objects are all solid squares that you can't collide with.

Comment: Well, try without the `break` and see what you get.

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Hmm, I wonder why it's not working in my game then. For some reason the player constantly glitches past the walls. The collision doesn't seem very stable. I'm going to accept your answer, but any idea why that might be happening? My code looks like this: https://pastebin.com/f3EWHmpx

Comment: Your code looks a bit different. Notice in my answer that the call to `getCircleRectangleDisplacement` is made with the *original* position, not the (temporarily) moved one. I don't know if this call maps to your call to `getSlidingVelocity`, ... but if so, you should do the same.

Comment: Oh yeah, good call. Hm, the bug is still occurring with that change made, but this would be too hard for you to debug with me just posting random snippets. Thanks anyways! I'll try to figure it out. You've given me a great base to work with.